# running pug from command line

Tags: node.js, pug

After I do `npm i -g jade` I'm able to use it via CLI, for instance `jade --help` works.
But after I install it's successor pug with `npm i -g pug`, running `pug --help` or `pug --version` gives `-bash: pug: command not found`.

I noticed that `/usr/local/bin/jade` is there, but there is no `pug` in the same folder.

I use homebrew on a mac if it matters.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A week ago, the CLI was sepearated to a separate package as mentioned in this commit : https://github.com/pugjs/pug/commit/2c373c17a514e1527f12eb6667685f843f1933a9

So now you need to do : `npm install pug-cli -g`